# QWizard behaves weird in QMdiArea

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt4

I have a QWizard that is a subwindow of a QMdiArea. A few weird things occur, but I assume they are all related, so I'll describe the easiest. Under Windows with an Aero theme, the following code behaves strange:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui

def createIntroPage():
    page = QtGui.QWizardPage()
    page.setTitle("Introduction")
    label = QtGui.QLabel("This wizard will help you register your copy of "
    "Super Product Two.")
    label.setWordWrap(True)
    layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
    layout.addWidget(label)
    page.setLayout(layout)
    return page

def createRegistrationPage():
    page = QtGui.QWizardPage()
    page.setTitle("Registration")
    page.setSubTitle("Please fill both fields.")
    nameLabel = QtGui.QLabel("Name:")
    nameLineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit()
    emailLabel = QtGui.QLabel("Email address:")
    emailLineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit()
    layout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
    layout.addWidget(nameLabel, 0, 0)
    layout.addWidget(nameLineEdit, 0, 1)
    layout.addWidget(emailLabel, 1, 0)
    layout.addWidget(emailLineEdit, 1, 1)
    page.setLayout(layout)
    return page

def createConclusionPage():
    page = QtGui.QWizardPage()
    page.setTitle("Conclusion")
    label = QtGui.QLabel("You are now successfully registered. Have a nice day!")
    label.setWordWrap(True)
    layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
    layout.addWidget(label)
    page.setLayout(layout)
    return page

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    main.setWindowTitle('Test MDI Application')
    mdiArea = QtGui.QMdiArea(main)
    main.setCentralWidget(mdiArea)

    wizard = QtGui.QWizard(main)
    wizard.addPage(createIntroPage())
    wizard.addPage(createRegistrationPage())
    wizard.addPage(createConclusionPage())
    wizard.setWindowTitle("Trivial Wizard")

    mdiArea.addSubWindow(wizard)
    wizard.show()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(wizard.exec_())
```

[image: Startup error]

Notice the buttons are all missing. After resizing, the buttons appear, but cannot be clicked. They can only be activated by tabbing to them and activating them with space.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a PyQT4 issue?

Comment: Seem to work as expected for me on Linux. Don't know if this will help, but that `wizard.exec_()` at the end looks weird - surely `app.exec_()` would make more sense...

Comment: As I said in the post, it fails with Aero (on Windows)

Comment: Also, you are right about the app.exec_(), this is just a test, and that doesn't make a difference

Comment: Well, by testing on another platform, I was ruling out the possibility that there was anything fundamentally wrong with your code, or with PyQt4 (which were the actual questions you asked). But really, if you suspected this was a problem specific to the Aero theme on Windows, your first port of call should not be SO. In a few minutes of web searching, I found [this Qt bug report](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-10478), which seems relevant. (You could also try experimenting with the [wizard-style](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwizard.html#WizardStyle-enum)).

Comment: I wasn't sure if I was doing something wrong that mostly had no consequences (like calling `wizard.exec_()` instead of `app.exec_()`) but failed in a certain circumstance, or if is was a bug. I'll look into your suggestions, thanks.